# getting a "cannot find method" error in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have built the code below and when I run it I keep getting an error message of
"cannot find method copyTo(sheet)"

It is coming on the line when I try to copy to the target sheets.  All the copyTo lines give the same error: source_sheet1.copyTo(target_sheet1);

Edit:  I have changed the code but still get the same error:

```
function UpdateCore() {

  //Set Target (Core sheets to use)
  var FindThisCore = "Compliance Spreadsheet Template- Sandton";
  var fileCore = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + FindThisCore+ '" and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"')
  while (fileCore.hasNext()) {
    var fileCoreMonth = fileCore.next();
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileCoreMonth.getId());
    var getmonthsheet = target.getSheetByName("Run me")
    var range = getmonthsheet.getRange(2,2); 
    var NewMonth = range.getValue();}

  //Set compliance file to use  
  var FindThisMonth = "Compliance Spreadsheet Sandton " + NewMonth

  //Set the Source values (Monthly Values)
  var fileThisMonth = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + FindThisMonth + '" and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"') 
  while (fileThisMonth.hasNext()) {
     var fileMonth = fileThisMonth.next();
     var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileMonth.getId());}

  CopyToSheet(source,target,"Guiding", "Guiding");
  CopyToSheet(source,target,"Learning", "Learning");
  CopyToSheet(source,target,"Bookkeeping", "Bookkeeping");
  CopyToSheet(source,target,"Fees", "Fees");
}
```

Which calls

```
function CopyToSheet (SourceFile, TargetFile, SourceSheet, TargetSheet){

  var SourceSheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SourceFile.getId());
  var TargetSheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TargetFile.getId());
  var sourcetoread = SourceSheetFile.getSheetByName(SourceSheet);
  var targettowrite = TargetSheetFile.getSheetByName(TargetSheet);

  sourcetoread.copyTo(targettowrite);
}
```

I have checked that it is connecting to the correct sheets by having it clear the sheets in the target and source- but the copyTo is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your code by this function:

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetundefined = ss.getSheetByName("badName");
  var sheetdefined = ss.getSheetByName("existingName");
  sheetdefined.copyTo(sheetdefined);
}
```

This way the error "cannot find method copyTo..." is triggered.

If you try to use "copyTo" on a undefined object, it will throw the error message "cannot invoke method copyTo of null".
So I guess this simply means, you should check beforehands if your sheets are defined and your target and source are not the same object, maybe this way.

```
if(sheet != undefined && targetSheet != undefined &&
   sheet.getSheetId != targetSheet.getSheetId){
  sheet.copyTo(targetSheet);
}
```

Comment: I have checked= all files are defined and in debug mode getting the urls of the files show the correct files are being pointed to by the variables.  I have tried to simplify it by sending the parameters to another function to do the copy, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you also check if the sheet ids are not equal, when you use copyTo function?

Comment: Yep- different ids, if I do a .clear on the sheet it clears the sheet (that is on source.clear the source is cleared, on target.clear the target is cleared) the only sheet functionality that seems to be confused is the copyTo

Comment: If you can define your problem in a more generic way and reproduce this error, maybe you've found a bug ;)
But the way your question is formulated, its not clear whether this is a bug, which can be reproduced.

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug or an issue with my code, hence my asking here...  To me the code looks right but I ma hoping people with more experience in writing google script can find the issue I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:  I was using the copyto method addressing the target sheet, I changed it to on the file and it works perfectly.  The change was very simple, in the function above I changed

```
sourcetoread.copyTo(targettowrite);
```

to

```
sourcetoread.copyTo(TargetSheetFile);
```

Since I wanted it to overwrite the existing sheet of that name.  I changed the overall function to delete the existing sheet, copy in the new name and then rename it to the original name (rather than the "Copy to..." name automatically assigned).  the full new function looks like this

```
function CopyToSheet (SourceFile, TargetFile, SourceSheet, TargetSheet){

  var SourceSheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SourceFile.getId());
  var TargetSheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TargetFile.getId());
  var sourcetoread = SourceSheetFile.getSheetByName(SourceSheet);
  var targettowrite = TargetSheetFile.getSheetByName(TargetSheet);
  TargetSheetFile.deleteSheet(targettowrite);

  sourcetoread.copyTo(TargetSheetFile);
  var RenameSheet = "Copy of " + TargetSheet; 
  var RenameThis = TargetSheetFile.getSheetByName(RenameSheet);
  RenameThis.setName(SourceSheet)

}
```